# How to retrieve String's and write them to a file or resource and overrwrite and reuse it?

Tags: android

I am retrieving about 7 URL's from a service. I want to be able to write these URL's some where and have my application read from them in another activity.

The thing that makes this tricky is the URL's change every week. So i would need to overwrite the current URL's. I don't want to make the url's stack up on top of each other where they never overrite and by the end of a month there are 24 unused URL's.

What and how is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Use `SharedPreferences`**!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

lol here is a sample:

```
public void SetUrls(String url[]) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("url0", url[0]);
    editor.putString("url1", url[1]);
    editor.putString("url2", url[2]);
    editor.putString("url3", url[3]);
    editor.putString("url4", url[4]);
    editor.putString("url5", url[5]);
    editor.putString("url6", url[6]);
    editor.commit();
}

public String[] getUrls() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    String url[] = new String[7];
    url[0] = settings.getString("url0", "default");
    url[1] = settings.getString("url1", "default");
    url[2] = settings.getString("url2", "default");
    url[3] = settings.getString("url3", "default");
    url[4] = settings.getString("url4", "default");
    url[5] = settings.getString("url5", "default");
    url[6] = settings.getString("url6", "default");
    return url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with SharedPreference but i didnt think to use it here. Do you think it is reliable enough for what i need to do? And it will overwrite its current information pertaining the a url key?

Comment: Yes I suppose that is its job! just like a map

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on your client implementation, you can store them in sqlite, or in local cache or shared preferences. Android allows apps to have a small cache.

As you store your urls you can timestamp them and check if they have expired and stuff.

Refere to the docs on android [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) facilities.

Comment: I think as Sherif stated above SharedPreference would be more reliable for this example.